# Installing Jupyter in AWS EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter

I have been following the steps below to install Jupyter in AWS EC2: 
https://chrisalbon.com/aws/basics/run_project_jupyter_on_amazon_ec2/

I gave 8888 as port.
I then launched jupyter notebook:

[image]

Then I go on my instance url:
https://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XXX.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com:8888/

I have a public IP so I also tried https://XX-XX-XX-XXX:8888/

But it does not load anything in both ways.
I made sure that 8888 port is authorized in security groups on my EC2 instance.
Any idea how I can deep dive where the issue is?

[EDIT 1]:

I followed these steps:

```
c = get_config()

# Kernel config
c.IPKernelApp.pylab = 'inline'  # if you want plotting support always in your notebook

# Notebook config
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/home/ec2-user/Notebooks/certs/Mycert_file.pem' #location of your certificate file
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False  #so that the ipython notebook does not opens up a browser by default
c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'  #the encrypted password we generated above
# Set the port to 8888, the port we set up in the AWS EC2 set-up
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
```

[EDIT 2]:

Previously to these steps I did this:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout Mycert_file.pem -out Mycert_file.pem
```

Now, to locate my .pem file I did the following: `find /home -name *.pem`

I found the location of my .pem file which is `/home/ec2-user/Notebooks/certs/Mycert_file.pem`

[EDIT 3]:

I will also add that I am already currently running a RStudio session on this instance on a 8787 port. I assume this is not impacting what I am doing trying to install Jupyter) but just wanted to point it out in case of.

Comment: Don't you see that it says you can only access it from `localhost`? You need to enable remote access: https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#running-a-public-notebook-server

Comment: Yes, I edited my post. I followed the steps to configure Jupyter, the issue is probably in one of these steps. I am not clear on where is my certificate file is located in my EC2 instance database as the only location of my .pem file is in my local folder.

Comment: Well, it seems that your jupyter notebook is not using your config file. Or it should says something like "The Jupyter Notebook is running at: https://[all ip address on your system]:8888/" instead of "http://localhost:8888/?token=....". And that certfile is exactly the file you generate using `openssl`.

Comment: BTW, this is not a general way(but simple enough for a newcomer) to host a jupyter server. Mostly we use `Nginx` or something else as a reverse proxy. So that we only need to expose 443 port.

Comment: I also agree that my config file is not being used, but how can I track where this is going wrong? I will edit my post to details steps I followed

Comment: You could use `jupyter notebook --debug` to enable debug log. And it will show you where does it look for config file.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue, regarding the config file. In the tutorial it said to press `esc`key to record the config file. But that was not saving the file for me. So I simply used `:wq!` and it saved it for me.

But I still can't make it work.
So, as advised, I used `jupyter notebook --debug`
Here are the logs:
[image]